# Variable Changing Function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

My Calculus 2 professor always opts to use his own notations on everything. So, yesterday he introduces us to a term I've never even heard of; "Variable changing function", with this problem:

The surface of an area $S$ is described the equation $f(x_1,\ldots,x_d)=0$, whereas $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$. If the function $g:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$, changes the coordinate system, in a way that the point $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ is described by the new variables $(y_1,\ldots,y_d)$, find how the surface of the area $S$ is transformed when changing the coordinate system according to $g$.

He told us that the solution is $h$'s gradient, where $h:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ is the composition of $f$ and $g$, $(f\circ g)=f(g(x_1,\ldots,x_d))$, which according to chain rule should be
$$
\nabla h(x)=\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1}x_1,\ldots,\,\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_d}x_d\right)=\nabla f(g(x))\cdot Dg(x)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}g(x_1),\ldots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_d}g(x_d)\right)\cdot \left[\begin{matrix}\dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1}x_1&\cdots&\dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_d}x_d\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ \dfrac{\partial g_d}{\partial x_1}x_1 & \cdots &\dfrac{\partial g_d}{\partial x_d}x_d\end{matrix}\right],
$$
and stopped there. I think he meant the partial derivative of $h$ in respect of $x_1,\ldots,x_d$ accordingly would give us how each of the variable would change after changing coordinates system, but he didn't clarify further.

If anyone who's even heard of the of the term "variable changing function" can suggest some bibliography that describes it more in depth? I'm kinda lost here.

P.S. I did my best translating that for the original Greek that it was given to me, I hope i didn't mess anything up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's well known that under a change of coordinates, the volume element changes by the Jacobian determinant.

I learned about it in Marsden and Tromba's *Vector Calculus*.

In rectangular it's $\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d}\d x_1\d x_2\dots\d x_n$.  In the new coordinates you have the Jacobian times the differentials.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I got it now. So technically you change the coordinate system, and the gradient of $h$ show how each variable was change after the transformation.

Comment: For instance, and one you will learn, the Jacobian of the change from rectangular to spherical is $\rho\sin\phi$.  So the volume element goes from $\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d}\d x\d y\d z$ to $\rho\sin\phi\d\phi\d\rho\d\theta$.

Comment: sorry, i blew that.  it's $\rho^2\sin\phi$.